# Bash on WindowsでpyenvにAnaconda3-5.0.0をインストールしようとしてますが、ハマってます

Tags: bash, anaconda, pyenv, wsl

環境：Windows10, Bash on Windows(Ubuntu16.0.4)

pyenvは正常に動いており、最新版にアップデート済なのですが、Anacondaのインストールができません。Bash on WindowsでのAnacondaのインストールは初です。
下記が内容です。※書き損じや勘違いなどあったらすみません。

```
$ pyenv install anaconda3-5.0.0
  Downloading Anaconda3-5.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh...
-> https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
Installing Anaconda3-5.0.0-Linux-x86_64...
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using python-build 1.1.5-4-g34a5b7f)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20171008174759.141
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20171008174759.141.log

Last 10 log lines:
installing: ipywidgets-7.0.0-py36h7b55c3a_0 ...
installing: jupyterlab-0.27.0-py36h86377d0_2 ...
installing: odo-0.5.1-py36h90ed295_0 ...
installing: scikit-image-0.13.0-py36had3c07a_1 ...
installing: spyder-3.2.3-py36he38cbf7_1 ...
installing: _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf-0.1.0-py36he11e457_0 ...
installing: blaze-0.11.3-py36h4e06776_0 ...
installing: jupyter-1.0.0-py36h9896ce5_0 ...
installing: anaconda-5.0.0-py36h06de3c5_0 ...
installation finished.
```

一部のファイルはインストールされているのですが、~/.pyenv配下のversions/Anaconda3-5.0.0の中にbinがなく、Anacondaの実行ができません。試しにAnaconda単体のインストールをした際は、問題なくインストールできたのですが、pyenvで管理していきたいのです。
※Anaconda単体では、Pythonやcondaの実行までできました

エラーを見ると、

```
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

とあり、下記の注釈に従い色々調べてみました。（3時間くらい...）

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.

上記エラー下のgitリンクを見ると（まだリンクを2個以上貼れずすみません）、

```
If you have homebrew openssl and pyenv installed, you may need to tell the 
compiler where the openssl package is located
```

訳：homebrew opensslとpyenvがインストールされている場合、opensslパッケージがどこにあるかコンパイラに伝える必要がある。

とのことでした。
※ついでに不足パッケージがないかと下記の様に色々インストールも試しましたが、全て最新版が入ってます

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev 
libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-
dev xz-utils tk-dev
```

対策の解説をみると、

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/openssl \
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64 \
pyenv install -v 3.4.3
```

上記の様にopensslの場所を明示して、最新版にしろ？的な内容が書いてあったので、上記の通りにやってみましたがだめでした。（macの解説しかなかったのですが、ぐぐったところUbuntuでも同じ感じに見えたので）

他にも、同様にpyenvでAnacondaを入れている人の記事を読んでみたのですが、同じ様にハマっているものがありませんでした。
上記エラー内容はいくつか記事でありましたが、解決策は別の感じでした。

下記のエラーも出ていますが、こちらはぐぐっても情報があまり見つからず、まだよくわかっていません。

```
BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using python-build 1.1.5-4-g34a5b7f)
```

長文となり恐縮ですが、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: お二方、ご回答ありがとうございます。御礼が遅くなり申し訳ありません。私もとりあえずは古いバージョンをインストールしました。
mmm様の方法、斬新ですね。試してみます！

Answer (score 1):

僕も同じような問題に直面しました。
今のやり方はあきらめました。

代わりにこのやり方でインストールしました。
１．anacondaのホームページからLinux用のshファイルをダウンロード
２．$sudo bash ファイルの場所　
をbash on ubuntu で実行。このときcドライブへのアクセスは　/mnt/c　としないと場所を認識してくれません。¥ではなく/であることにも注意してください。

Answer (score 0):

自分も全く同じエラー内容に遭遇しました。
ただ、その他のバージョンだと問題なくインストールでき、動作も確認できました。
（すべて試したわけではありませんが、たとえばanaconda3-4.4.0など。）
特に最新版にこだわりが無いようであれば問題ないかと思いますが、いかがでしょうか？